# How to add capybara dsl syntax highlighting to vim syntax highlighting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rails.vim

I'm using Tim Pope's rails.vim plugin and for the most part it highlights nearly everything I want, except Capybara's new DSL which contains keywords like `feature`, `scenario`, `background` etc.

I don't want to create a new syntax file just for those two keywords, just need to add them to the existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found `rails.vim` file which holds syntax stuff and added the keywords.

```
elseif buffer.type_name('spec') syn keyword rubyRailsTestMethod describe context it its specify shared_examples_for it_should_behave_like before after subject fixtures controller_name helper_name feature scenario background
```

This answer gave me the hint where to look: [Automate rails.vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014441/automate-rails-vim)